# Filling in each of the 9 areas in circle using R

Tags: r, plot

Looking for a way to fill in each of the different parts of this circle, which is used in visualizing the thickness of the different parts of the retina. Using data from Excel, the different parts will be highlighted if the variable is `1` (and not if the variable is `empty`).

```
library(plotrix)
plot(1,1,col="white",bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="1",ann=FALSE)
draw.circle(1,1,0.3)
draw.circle(1,1,.15)
draw.circle(1,1,.05)
arrows(0.77787,0.77787, 0.962644661,0.962644661,length=0)
arrows(1.037355339,1.037355339, 1.22213,1.22213, length=0)
arrows(0.77787,1.22213,0.962644661,1.037355339,length=0)
arrows(1.037355339,0.962644661,1.22213,0.77787,length=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Use `segments` instead of `arrows`.

Comment: Also my guess is you will probably have to do some good old fashioned math, trace out and save curves with `curve`, then use the points you traced out to fill in `polygon` shapes. That sounds tedious so I hope for your sake there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `pie` and `draw.circle`:

```
library(plotrix)
library(RColorBrewer)

cols <- brewer.pal(9, 'Set3')

pie(rep(1, 4), col=cols[1:4], init.angle=45, radius=1, labels='')
par(new=TRUE)
pie(rep(1, 4), col=cols[5:8], init.angle=45, radius=0.5, labels='')
draw.circle(0, 0, 0.166, col=cols[9])
```

[image: retina]

Set `col` as necessary to fill (or not) the individual sections, e.g.:

```
pie(rep(1, 4), col=c(0, 0, 'gray80', 0), init.angle=45, radius=1, labels='')
par(new=TRUE)
pie(rep(1, 4), col=rep(0, 4), init.angle=45, radius=0.5, labels='')
draw.circle(0, 0, 0.166, col='gray80')
```

[image: retina2]